# Enter key skips angularJS validations

Tags: angularjs, validation, coffeescript, enter

I have the following form:

```
<form role="form" name="weightForm" ng-submit="save()">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="weight">Today's Weight</label>
     <input ng-model="post.weight" name="weight" ng-required="true"
         type="number" min="10" max="800" class="form-control"
         ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0,5])?$/" step="0.5"
         placeholder="Enter your weight in lbs">
  </div>
```

And here is the code for my save button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()"
      ng-disabled="weightForm.weight.$invalid">
Save</button>
```

This input is supposed to only accept integer numbers and float under following format : `n.0 or n.5 (see Regex)`

When I type in an unaccepted value, the save button grey out and can't save typed value. But, I noticed, `Enter Key` can sometimes skip validations. For instance, if a user type in `12.` the validations are skipped even tough the save button is greyed out.

Does anyone have an idea about how preventing this from happening.

Comment: show the controller functions `submit()` and `save()`. Not sure why you need a `ng-click` on button in the first place

Comment: I copied the wrong code .. it is save button, not submit(see edited code). Also, from [AngularJS Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-), I saw I can pass `$event` as argument as `<form ng-submit="save($event)">`. Is there a possible way to couple this event with `weightForm.$errors` to prevent this behavior?

Comment: well that dosn't make sense having 2 event handlers using same method. The button click will also trigger form submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it this way:

I declared my form as following:

```
<form role="form" name="weightForm" ng-submit="save(weightForm)">
```

My save button as:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()"
      ng-disabled="weightForm.weight.$invalid">
```

In my controller:

The save method is called whenever user clicks on `Enter Key`

```
$scope.save = (weightForm) ->
  if weightForm.$error.pattern == undefined
  #If weightForm.$error.pattern == undefined, then there is no errors and content can be saved...
```

The submit method is called whenever user clicks on `save` button:

```
$scope.submit = ->
#Button status depends on `ng-disabled`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the number of objects in form.$error. If the number is greater than zero exit the submit function. This happens because you aren't submitting the form directly.

```
if(Object.keys(form.$error).length  > 0) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: There is no field $errors in form. But, there is a field called $error

Comment: That would be the one sorry. I was working from memory.

Comment: I solved the problem based on your answer. Please see my answer